# How to get deep relation in Entity Framework in many to many relation?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have following many to many relations:

```
PersonBook; BookAuthor; BookGenre;
```

I can get a `Person`'s `Books`, but it does not contain `Author` and `Genre` list.

I created a model for each class and map entity object to that model.

**Solution in EF6:**

```
 Person person = db.Person
                 .Where(p => p.PersonID == 1)
                 .Include(p => p.Books.Select(b => b.Authors))
                 .Include(p => p.Books.Select(g => g.Genres))
                 .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I'm surprised it actually returns books. Based on your query I'd say you're missing include. Are you using EF or EF Core?

Comment: <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"> EF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get related data in Entity FrameworkCore the best choise is to use `Include()` and `ThenInclude()` methods:

```
Person person = db.Person
                .Where(p => p.PersonID == 1) // change this
                .Include(ba => ba.BookAuthor.Select(a => a.Author)
                .Include(bg => bg.BookGenre.Select(g => g.Genre)
                .First();
```

Comment: I don't have a BookAuthor class. I can't reach Books from Person with include,  but it comes with select. 

Here it is my EF generated Book constructor;

```
 public Person()
        {
            this.Books = new HashSet<Book>();
        }
public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }

```